# 4TB Seagate, End-to-End errors

Tags: hard-drive, raid, smart

I've got a seagate 4TB drive, part of a RAID0 array. It's ~4 years old, but every test I've thrown at it says it's clean, working great, and every SMART test I've tried, including Seagate's own SeaTools, passes.

However, when I view the individual SMART values, the value for B8, End-to-End Error value, is flagged bad and at 99 (max possible value, I believe)

I know there's no way to completely 'reset' the SMART info, but is there a (preferably non-destructive, data safe) way to clear JUST that value?

I'd like to track it, and see if it's caused by a bad cable, the drive itself, or simply a fluke from something over the last couple years or so.

Comment: "is there a (preferably non-destructive, data safe) way to clear JUST that value?" - No